# How to refresh HTML field on selecting the drop down list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get html field (a drop down list) refreshed as I get it by default on clicking the chart type from the (chart type) drop down list. The default selection after selecting a chart is shown below: (if I select "Pie Chart 2D" from the drop down list)

[image]

Now if I select another similar chart "Pie Chart 3D"  (which has same drop down field) and also I select the field data, then the image is as below:
[image]

**PROBLEM**

Now if I select the "Pie Chart 2D" back again from the drop down list I get this 2nd image field set already. I want the field to be refreshed as it is shown in the 1st image of Pie Chart 2D. Therefore, how should I refresh the field?

***NOTE:*** 
The field that I want to refresh to default is **"Define X-Axis"** drop down list.

I hope I have cleared my problem, in case of confusion in the understanding I will be replying soon. I hope it is not difficult to solve!

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You tagged jquery/js but I don't see them on your code.

Comment: I have not posted any code, I expect the solution from jquery/js experts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an `onchange` event listener to your select. If you have a function `updateDiv()` in JS that would update your `<div>` element that you want to call with a change of the `<select>` element:

In HTML:

```
<select id="chartType" onchange="resetFieldToDefault();">
```

In jQuery:

```
$("select#chartType").change(resetFieldToDefault);
```

In (plain) JS:

```
document.getElementById("chartType").addEventListener("change", resetFieldToDefault);
```

**EDIT**

I don't think I answered the question correctly above. I believe the question was more along the lines of, How could I deselect all the options in that field (once a select field was changed)? So I only answered the first part of the question, but the second part about resetting the other `<select>` element remains unsettled. (Am I correct?)

To do this, add a listener as shown above. And then, add the (plain) JS function:

```
var resetFieldToDefault = function() {
    var selectedOptions = document.getElementById("xAxisSelect").selectedOptions;
    for(var i = 0; i < selectedOptions.length; i++)
        selectedOptions[i].selected = false;
}
```

Comment: Let me re-phrase the above question more simply!

Comment: Please have a look on it again, I have re-phrased the question more simply!

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
$("#chartType).on("change", function() {
    refreshDivs(this.val());
});

function refreshDivs(value) {
    if(value=="Scatter Chart") {
        $("#divEventCategory").hide();
        $("#divEventSubCategory").hide();
    } else if ((value=="Bubble Chart") {
        $("#divEventCategory").show();
        $("#divEventSubCategory").show();
    }
}
```

If you need to refresh the content of the dropdowns/listboxes based on the choice, just add the code in the corresponding section as well.